# How can I get my container name when in a container in k8s pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I don't know how to set the env to get the container name.
for example,

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME MY_POD_NAMESPACE;
          printenv MY_POD_IP MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_CONTAINER_NAME
          value: "test-container"
```

I wonder that could the value of env:MY_CONTAINER_NAME be a kind of reference?

Comment: What would you do with the container name, if you had it?  (A pod will typically only have one [main] container, and you can't really do much with the container name without also having the pod name.)

Comment: You can use the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to get the pod name in an environment variable, but not the container name.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need the container name you can use the `HOSTNAME` variable, so you can avoid defining a new env variable:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv HOSTNAME
          sleep 10;
        done;
```

if you *need* to have a new env variable, you can use anchors in the yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: &containername test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_CONTAINER_NAME;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_CONTAINER_NAME
          value: *containername
```

and then you get it:

```
$ kubectl logs dapi-envars-fieldref
test-container
```

Comment: The hostname(8) will usually be the _pod_ name, as distinct from the container name within the pod.